# AHCI required for new SSD?

Tags: ssd, motherboard, ide, ahci

I do not know too terribly much about computers, but I wanted to try to install SSD as my new boot drive. My computer does not have AHCI and I'm not sure how to update my BIOS or if it will even give me the option of AHCI if I do update it. I was wondering if AHCI was required for my SSD to work or if IDE will work? MY motherboard is a MSI 990FXA-GD80 (MS-7640) and I'm getting a 1TB WD SSD.

Comment: How are we supposed to answer your question without specifications for the SSD?

Comment: Please click [edit] and provide the model part number of the Western Digital SSD you are considering.

Comment: Make and specific model of PC?

Answer (score 1):

A BIOS update to the latest non-beta release (in your case, version 13.6) is always recommended if your [motherboard](https://download.msi.com/archive/mnu_exe/M7640v2.0_Euro.zip) BIOS is behind.

A 2.5" SATA SSD is plug-compatible with a 2.5" or 3.5" SATA HDD. It will work using the SATA ('IDE') settings in the BIOS, but it will work much better and live longer if AHCI is available.

There are NVMe (PCIe) SSDs as well, but those would require a controller, and I would avoid them with older motherboards, as I've tried adding them with no success.

Comment: "Better" means the TRIM feature works. TRIM can drastically extend the lifetime of your SSD.